# Spark Scala - Filter Timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to filter a timestamp between 2 values using Spark Scala (ignoring the date). I'm trying to only select all records between 9:00:00pm and 11:00:00pm (inclusive of 9:00:00 and 11:00:00). My current input, output, and code are listed below.

My thought process was to be able to filter using my pickupWindow column being greater than or less than my values.

Any thoughts?

Input:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+----------+------------+------------+
|tpep_pickup_datetime  |tpep_dropoff_datetime |total_amount|pickupWindow|
+----------------------+----------------------+----------+------------+------------+
|05/18/2018 09:09:29 PM|05/18/2018 09:52:53 PM|42.8        |09:09:29    |
|05/18/2018 11:00:00 PM|05/18/2018 11:09:13 PM|23.5        |11:00:00    |
|05/18/2018 02:47:21 PM|05/18/2018 03:30:00 PM|46.62       |02:47:21    |
```

Current Output:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
|tpep_pickup_datetime|tpep_dropoff_datetime|timestamp|total_amount|pickupWindow|
+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
+--------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Current Code:

```
stamp.withColumn("pickupWindow",date_format(to_timestamp(col("tpep_pickup_datetime"),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"hh:mm:ss")).select("tpep_pickup_datetime","tpep_dropoff_datetime","timestamp","total_amount","pickupWindow").filter(col("pickupWindow")>="9:00:00").filter(col("pickupWindow")<="11:00:00").where($"tpep_pickup_datetime".contains("PM")).show(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use **.geq** and **.leq** like below -

```
scala> df.withColumn("pickupWindow",date_format(to_timestamp(col("tpep_pickup_datetime"),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"hh:mm:ss")).filter(col("pickupWindow").geq("09:00:00") && col("pickupWindow").leq("11:00:00")).
    show()

    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
    |tpep_pickup_datetime  |tpep_dropoff_datetime |timestamp|total_amount|pickupWindow|
    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
    |05/18/2018 09:56:20 PM|05/18/2018 10:50:38 PM|35780    |52.87       |09:56:20    |
    |05/18/2018 10:52:49 PM|05/18/2018 11:08:47 PM|39169    |14.76       |10:52:49    |
    |05/18/2018 09:01:22 PM|05/18/2018 09:05:36 PM|32482    |6.3         |09:01:22    |
    |05/18/2018 09:00:29 PM|05/18/2018 09:05:31 PM|32429    |7.56        |09:00:29    |
    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

And if you want AM & PM conversion

```
scala> df.withColumn("pickupWindow",date_format(to_timestamp(col("tpep_pickup_datetime"),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"HH:mm:ss")).filter(col("pickupWindow").geq("21:00:00") && col("pickupWindow").leq("23:00:00")).
    show(false)
    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
    |tpep_pickup_datetime  |tpep_dropoff_datetime |timestamp|total_amount|pickupWindow|
    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
    |05/18/2018 09:56:20 PM|05/18/2018 10:50:38 PM|35780    |52.87       |21:56:20    |
    |05/18/2018 10:52:49 PM|05/18/2018 11:08:47 PM|39169    |14.76       |22:52:49    |
    |05/18/2018 09:01:22 PM|05/18/2018 09:05:36 PM|32482    |6.3         |21:01:22    |
    |05/18/2018 09:00:29 PM|05/18/2018 09:05:31 PM|32429    |7.56        |21:00:29    |
    +----------------------+----------------------+---------+------------+------------+
```